# Angular Heroes tutorial <app-heroes> css selector

Tags: html, css, angular

in the Angular tutorial https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1#selector, I dont understand the sentence: "The CSS element selector, 'app-heroes', matches the name of the HTML element that identifies this component within a parent component's template."
I don't know what  is like for a css selector, because I cannot find anything that matches the name of some HTML element.. there is no HTML element with the name app-heroes or similar... 
How does this work?

I only have a folder structure /src/app/heroes, where my heroes components are defined. Does it construct a name consisting of "parentfolder-folder"? and what exactly will be referenced by the css element selector ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I dont understand the sentence: "The CSS element selector,
>   'app-heroes', matches the name of the HTML element that identifies
>   this component within a parent component's template."

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
```

As you can see in the @Component it defines the `selector` with the value `app-heroes` this means that you will use `app-heroes` to be like html element (eg. `<div> </div>` therefore you will use `<app-heroes></app-heroes>`) to be able to show the view of HeroesComponent.

Answer (score 1):

Scroll down where it says [`Show the HeroesComponent view`](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1#show-the-heroescomponent-view). There you will see HTML:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<app-heroes></app-heroes>
```

So your CSS selector `app-heroes` matches this HTML node `<app-heroes></app-heroes>`. Same as CSS selector `h1{}` matches `<h1></h1>`

Comment: thanks nice, and that basically means, that my "template" or rather selector which refers to <app-heroes> will be bound inside the other html document? and which part gets replaced? will the whole code of my heroes.component.ts placed at that point or will only my heroes.component.html file be added at that place?

Comment: @user2883596 All code from AppHeroes component will be placed as child of `app-heroes`